# Pyro cms admin login

Tags: pyrocms

I have installed latest version of PyroCMS but I can´t login into admin section. 
When I filled out email and password fields and clicked on login button nothing happend. Website was loading until execution time has been reached....I have tried it in Chrome, Mozilla, IE, Safari....When I used Opera warning message has appeared : An Error Was Encountered The action you have requested is not allowed.

I´m using Wamp, Windows 8.
Thanks for help !

Comment: try a refresh install again

Comment: "Latest version" is 2.1.5 or 2.2.0-beta1? Got anything in your PHP logs?

Comment: I reinstalled wamp, and now it works. I think that was something with PHP settings..

Comment: Can you delete this question if its not relevant, or answer it yourself?